# How to check Internet bandwidth in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line-interface, internet

Instead of going to sites like http://speedtest.net , or others, I want to check my current Internet speed from the terminal on Ubuntu. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Theres a cli tool for speedtest.net:

https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

An other option would be to measure the download time for a big file (>100 MB) from a known to be fast server and calculate the current bandwidth from that. I wrote a munin plugin quite a time ago, which was doing this perfectly fine.

A good starting point is the following command:

`time(wget –output-document=/dev/null http:///files/downloadtest 2>/dev/null 1>&2)`

Comment: You will typically see more performance using multiple connections (Speedtest by Ookla actually does this) versus a single `wget`. Running multiple requests to different servers through parallel tasks or using something such as BitTorrent will typically provide a closer match to true peak numbers.

Comment: @henrik . I can't consider speedtest-cli to be in any way a valid test of network speed.It doesn't show my correct bandwidth.

Comment: @samie What do you consider as 'correct bandwidth'? The payed for bandwith often differs from the real one, also depending on daytime etc. From my experience speedtest.net ist quite reliable - Do you get different results from the webgui and the cli tool?

Comment: @Bert I think thats a thing, that is based on the caching and limiting of you provider. If you buy a dedicated 1Gbit Port, you'll get quite close to the theoretical maximum with a single connection if you have a sufficient peer (Amazon S3 e.g.)

Comment: @Henrik I am using a traffic controler in my network and i am using iperf and other things like cli tool and some sites to test my bandwidth.but the results in these are different and just iperf shows the correct bandwidth when I am using traffic controler.but my problem is that i want to use a tool to test my bandwidth when i am downloading and uploading a big file in long time when iperf tests my bandwidth in short time.

Answer (score 1):

Let my start by saying that *"your internet speed"* typically isn't fixed.

It depends on the path between your end of the connection and the other end-point. And along that path there can be traffic shaping, high bandwidth connections, slower links, congestion, low latency connections or high latency links (satellite uplink anyone?) etc. and the cumulative effect of all segments determines that effective *"speed"*, with the lowest bandwidth segment typically being the limiter on bandwidth and latency being cumulative.

But having said that:

`ethtool` will give the negotiated/configured link speed between your Linux server's ethernet device and whatever (typically the switch port) it is connected to:

```
ethtool  eth0
Settings for eth0:
    ...
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    ...
```

So the speed between my server and the switch is 1 GBit/s.

That of course doesn't even imply that I get such bandwidth when downloading research data from [McMurdo station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMurdo_Station) on Antarctica!

Another tool is [`iperf`](https://iperf.fr/) which can be used to measure maximum TCP/IP performance from the commandline.  You can use that to for instance measure the bandwidth you get between your server and your gateway and between your server the next hop from your gateway to your ISP.

Comment: `iPerf` is a great tool assuming you have access to another Linux server outside your network.

Comment: @HBruijn . I used iperf but i want to test my bandwidth when i am downloading or uploading a big file in long time.